# Create table name using username in Hive query running in Oozie workflow?

Tags: hive, hiveql, oozie, oozie-workflow

I've got a Hive SQL script/action as part of an Oozie workflow. I'm doing a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT to output the results. I want to name the table using the username plus an appended string (e.g. "User123456_output_table"), but can't seem to get the correct syntax.

```
set tablename=${hivevar:current_user()};
CREATE TABLE `${hiveconf:tablename}_output_table` AS SELECT ...
```

That doesn't work and gives:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: IllegalArgumentException java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${hivevar:current_user()%7D_output_table
```

Or changing the first line to set tablename=${current_user()}; starts running the SELECT query but eventually stops with:

```
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [${current_user()}_output_table]: is not a valid table name
```

Or changing the first line to set tablename=current_user(); starts running the SELECT query but eventually stops with:

```
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [current_user()_output_table]: is not a valid table name
```

Alternatively, is there a way to pass the username from the Oozie workflow via a parameter?

I'm using Hue to do all this rather than the command line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong: `set tablename=${hivevar:current_user()};` - it will not be resolved and substituted as is.

Hive does not calculate variables before substitution, it substitutes them as is, all functions in variables are NOT calculated. variables are just text replacement.

This:

```
set tablename=current_user();
CREATE TABLE `${hiveconf:tablename}_output_table` ...
```

gets resolved as

```
CREATE TABLE `current_user()_output_table` ...
```

And functions are not supported in table names, it will not work this way.

The solution is to calculate functions outside the script and pass them as parameters.

See this blog: https://prodlife.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/parameterizing-hive-actions-in-oozie-workflows/